# When trying to remove key/value from json file I get 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'/'del'

Tags: python, json

I have a json file with this structure:

```
{
  "collections": {
    "tags": {
      "2GvAB3TrWwJSdDeAdg4R": {
        "id": "",
        "aperances": 1,
        "tagName": "todolist",
        "__collections__": {}
      }
   }
}
```

what I want is to remove from the "2GvAB3TrWwJSdDeAdg4R" object(or the objects inside "tags") the attributes *"id"* and "*__ collections __*",
So i can have the object like:

```
{
"collections": {
   "tags": {
      "2GvAB3TrWwJSdDeAdg4R": {
         "aperances": 1,
         "tagName": "todolist",
        }
     }
}
```

This is the code I have tried but using `pop` or `del` will give me a `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute ...`.

```
import json
with open('jsontest.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for element in data:
        for attibute in element:
            attibute.pop('id', None)
            attibute.pop('_collections', None)

with open('jsontest.json', 'w') as data_file:
    data = json.dump(data, f)
```

Any help appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: `element` is the key `"collections"`, which is a string. You then iterate over every character of that string by doing `for attribute in element`, where `attribute` will be the current character (first, `attribute` will be `'c'`, then `'o'`, then `'l'`... those are all strings. Strings don't have a `.pop` method.)

Comment: JSON really isn't relevant here. There are exactly two things you can do related to JSON in Python: you can decode a JSON value to a regular Python object, or you can encode a Python object as a JSON value. You're just dealing with a regular Python `dict.`

Comment: You are completely doing it, wrong man..
.
it is not the way to iterate over a dictionary in python.
if you have the schema you can directly delete the values like this too

`f = open('jsontest.json', 'r+')`

`data = json.load(f)`

`del data['collections']['tags']['2GvAB3TrWwJSdDeAdg4R']['id']`

`del data['collections']['tags']['2GvAB3TrWwJSdDeAdg4R']['__collections__']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are accessing keys in for loop and not value. try following

```
data = {
  "collections": {
    "tags": {
      "2GvAB3TrWwJSdDeAdg4R": {
        "id": "",
        "aperances": 1,
        "tagName": "todolist",
        "__collections__": {}
      }
   }
}
}

for element in data:
    for tag in data[element]:
        for attribute in data[element][tag]:
            data[element][tag][attribute].pop('id', None)
            data[element][tag][attribute].pop('_collections', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you iterate over a dictionary, you just get the keys by default. We can see this by printing the variables in your code:

```py
for element in d:
    print(element)
    for attribute in element:
        print(attribute)
```

The first variable is a key, ie a string, and when we iterate it we get another string, ie each of its characters:

```
collections
c
o
l
l
e
c
t
i
o
n
s
```

The way I interpret the data, we can just index "collections" and "tags", and then iterate:

```py
for element in data:
    print(element)
    for attribute in element:
        print(attribute)        

collections = data["collections"]
tags = collections["tags"]

for k in tags:
    del(tags[k]["id"])
    del(tags[k]["__collections__"])

print(data)
# {'collections': {'tags': {'2GvAB3TrWwJSdDeAdg4R': {'aperances': 1, 'tagName': 'todolist'}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are completely doing it wrong man, this is not the way to iterate over a dictionary in python. if you have the schema you can directly delete the values like this too and after that you can dump data to file.

```
import json
with open('jsontest.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print("Orignal Data: ",data)
    del data['collections']['tags']['2GvAB3TrWwJSdDeAdg4R']['id']
    del data['collections']['tags']['2GvAB3TrWwJSdDeAdg4R']['__collections__']
    print("Updated Data: ",data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that too

```
with open(r'jsontest.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    del(data["collections"]["tags"]["2GvAB3TrWwJSdDeAdg4R"]['id'])
    del(data["collections"]["tags"]["2GvAB3TrWwJSdDeAdg4R"]['__collections__'])
```

result:

```
{'collections': {'tags': {'2GvAB3TrWwJSdDeAdg4R': {'aperances': 1, 'tagName': 'todolist'}}}}
```